# Trigonometric equation. How to find $\phi$?

Tags: trigonometry

$$29.7=21.9 \sin(\tfrac{\pi}{6}.1-\phi)+51.6$$

Here $\phi=\tfrac{2\pi}{3}$

Graph this equation and the regression equation on the same graph.

Can someone help me find theta algebraically. I know what the answer is but I don't know how to get to it. IF you could show every step. I'm confused how to get rid of the sin and parentheses to get theta by itself.

Comment: Please transfer the image into text here, so others can search and find your problem.

Comment: That symbol is called phi buddy

Comment: What have you tried? Can you manipulate the equation to the form $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6} - \phi\right) = $ something?

Comment: I have typed your text patiently. Have the same patience next time you ask a question. Taking a photograph for a single formula is not a good solution.

Comment: @JeanMarie I just meant phi, the buddy was referring to Kvend, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Let me allow in these Corona Virus times some humor : in your last sentence your objective is "getting rid of the sin" : no, you will not be able, or you are a saint.

Answer (score 2):

$$29.7=21.9\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}*1-\phi)+51.6$$
Find $\phi$

Okay so we can do the arithemtic, once we're done with that we're left with $$-1=\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}*1-\phi)$$

Due to the nature of the $\sin$ function we have multiple values for $\sin(x)=-1$ **
[image]

Since $sin$ equals $-1$ once every cycle, and every cycle is of length $2\pi$, we have $x=\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi k$ for ** where k is any integer

From here we can see that in your problem we have $$\frac{\pi}{6}*1-\phi=\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi k$$

So $$\phi=\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{3\pi}{2}-2\pi k$$

So doing the arithmetic on the left side we have:
$$\phi=-\frac{4\pi}{3}-2\pi k$$

So we have $\phi=\frac{2\pi}{3}$ when $k=-1$

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:
\begin{align}
29.7= &21.9 \sin \Bigl(\frac{\pi}{6} \cdot 1 - \phi \Bigr) + 51.6\iff 21.9 \sin \Bigl(\frac{\pi}{6} - \phi \Bigr)=29.7-51.6=-21.9 \\
\iff &\sin \Bigl(\frac{\pi}{6} - \phi \Bigr)=-1\iff \frac{\pi}{6} - \phi\equiv -\frac{\pi}{2}\mod 2\pi \\
\iff &\phi\equiv \frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{2\pi}{3}\mod 2\pi
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$29.7 = 21.9 \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{6} \cdot 1 - \phi \right) + 51.6$$

$$29.7 - 51.6 = 21.9 \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{6} \cdot 1 - \phi \right)$$

$$\frac{29.7 - 51.6}{21.9} = \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{6} \cdot 1 - \phi \right)$$

$$\sin^{-1} \left( \frac{29.7 - 51.6}{21.9} \right) = \frac{\pi}{6} \cdot 1 - \phi$$

$$\sin^{-1} \left( \frac{29.7 - 51.6}{21.9} \right) - \frac{\pi}{6} = - \phi$$

$$ -\sin^{-1} \left( \frac{29.7 - 51.6}{21.9} \right) + \frac{\pi}{6}= \phi$$